# Alexa ASK SDK V2 Nodejs Dialog Delegate Directive overriding the card response

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am using ASK SDK V2 for node.js to develop an alexa skill. According to the documentation, we need to add Inprogress as well as Completed dialog handlers to implement dialog Delegation. It is working properly, but the response is somehow overriding the response which I am expecting.

The Inprogress intent handler:

```
const InProgressGetAuthors = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest' &&
            handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'GetAuthors' &&
            handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.dialogState !== 'COMPLETED';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const currentIntent = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent;
        if (handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.dialogState === "STARTED") {
            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .addDelegateDirective(currentIntent)
                .getResponse();
        } else if (handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.dialogState !== 'COMPLETED') {
            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .addDelegateDirective()
                .getResponse();
        } else {
            return currentIntent;
        }
    }
}
```

The completed intent handler:

```
const CompletedGetAuthors = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest' &&
            handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'GetAuthors';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(author_propmt)
            .reprompt(author_propmt)
            .withStandardCard(
                author_title,
                author_copy,
                author.imageUrl,
                author.imageUrl
            )
            .withShouldEndSession(false)
            .getResponse(); 
    }
}
```

In the completed intent handler I am sending card in the response. It does speak out the text, but the card is not displayed in response.

The response object:

```
{
    "body": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "response": {
            "directives": [
                {
                    "type": "Dialog.Delegate"
                }
            ]
        },
        "sessionAttributes": {},
        "userAgent": "ask-node/2.0.9 Node/v6.10.3"
    }
}
```

If you look at the response body the card is missing. What am I doing wrong ? Could anyone please let me know ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this issue add the following condition in the Inprogress intent handler:

```
    handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.dialogState !== 'COMPLETED' &&
    handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.dialogState !== 'IN_PROGRESS';
```

The card is getting displayed now.

Thanks